# Rails API Image Upload with Active Storage / S3, React and ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, rails-api

I have created an app using a Rails API with a React front-end and ActiveAdmin as the CMS back-end, which is based off of [this tutorial](https://blog.heroku.com/a-rock-solid-modern-web-stack). I am adding on a model which includes an image using ActiveStorage for file uploads, as well as S3 for storage on production.

*app/models/photo.rb*

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :image
end
```

*app/controllers/photos_controller.rb*

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Serialization
  before_action :set_photo, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /photos
  def index
    @photos = Photo.all
    render json: @photos.to_json
  end

  ...

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:image, :location_name, :region, :url)
  end
end
```

*app/serializers/photo_seralizer.rb*

```
class PhotoSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :image, :location_name, :region, :url

  def image
    rails_blob_path(object.image, only_path: true) if object.image.attached?
  end
end
```

When I view the API endpoint, the attached image is not showing in the photo object, here is an example return. Is there something I'm missing in the Serializer, that isn't adding in the related image? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
[{
  "id":1,
  "location_name":"Acreage Ciderhouse",
  "region":"Northern Metro",
  "url":"https://example.com/acreage-ciderhouse/",
  "created_at":"2020-01-09T15:18:33.298-07:00",
  "updated_at":"2020-01-09T15:27:40.594-07:00"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The activestorage saves data different, I think your index is calling data from your model table, but images are saved in relationship to other tables. So following is way to check if image is really saved use rails console to check.

```
rails c
@photo = Photo.find(1)
puts @photo.image.attached?
```

If you get true that image is saving properly now you can do following to add all image urls in your request

```
def index
@photos = Photo.all
@photos.each do |p|
   if @photo.present? 
     image_url = { :image => (url_for p.image) }
     p.attributes.merge(image_url)
    end
end
render json: @photos.to_json
end
```

I did not test above code, just wrote, but I used it a lot for my apis.